# Symfony2 & Doctrine set foreign key to null

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fatal-error

I want to unset a nullable foreign key in my table cookie, which is here represented as ORM entity object `$cookie`:

```
$cookie->setFsession(new Doctrine_Null());
$this->em->persist($cookie);
$this->em->flush();
```

But I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'GroupConsulter\dotplus\FrontEndBundle\Doctrine_Null' not found
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Doctrine_Null does not exist anymore. This is not symfony 1.x!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is Doctrine_Null class? If you added some vendor with this class you need use appropriate namespace for it.

But for you needs, just enough will be:

```
$cookie->setFsession(null);
```